# How to create invisible element with size of a point on mousedown and make it always keep position in respect to its creator?

Tags: jquery, html, mouseevent

So we have a `<p class="ex" id="grumble3">button</p>` we want to set such `$('#grumble3').mouseup(function(){` that would create a point sized div on top of mouse up point. And that new div shall always be 'on top' of its creator element (meaning in case of resize events or body html changes). Is such thing possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible using `jQuery(selector).css()` method and the css `z-index` rule.
You yould have something like this:

```
$('#grumble3').mouseup(function(){
    var elemZIndex = $(this).css('z-index');
    var elemPos = $(this).offset();

    $('body').append('<div class="new" style="position:absolute; left:' + elemPos.left + 'px; top:' + elemPos.top + 'px; z-index:'+ (elemZIndex+10) +'">&nbsp;</div>');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#grumble3').mouseup(function(){
var elemZIndex = $(this).css('z-index','100');//Making SureThat this element stays on top
var elemPos = $(this).offset();

$('body').append('<div class="new" style="position:absolute; left:' + elemPos.left + 'px; top:' + elemPos.top + 'px; z-index:'+ (elemZIndex+10) +'">&nbsp;</div>');});
```